# Convert Crystal Report to Telerik Report with Standalone Designer

Tags: crystal-reports, telerik, reporting, error-reporting

I have `Crystal report` files and I need convert to `trdx file` with `Telerik Report with Standalone Designer`.

Actually I using `Crystal Reports version 14.1.4.1327` and my machine support `64 bit`, but I get this error.

> "Could not load file or assembly
>   'CrystalDesicions.CrystalReports.Engine,version=10.2.3600.0 ,
>   culture=Neutral'. PublicKeyToken=''692bea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies.The system cannot file the file specified."

Comment: use the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022, input command 

gacutil -l CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

get the version number and PublickeyToken add to Telerik.ReportDesigner.exe.config file

Answer (score 0):

Telerik report support migrate from crystal report requires build 10.2.3600.0 or later.

For understanding more.
http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/faq-available-converters.html
http://www.telerik.com/forums/convert-crystal-report-with-report-designer-8cf8f8b5443d

So it want to that version, but as you have CR 14.1.4 version, so dll reference need to be update manually.

This is nothing but reference dll error which does not you have.

Check this link.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/conversion-of-crystal-report-into-telerik-report

http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/details/converting-reports-from-various-versions-of-crystalreports